# Are images in data-src attributed downloaded on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lazy-loading

In the [Lazy Load plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_fadein.html) we mention the `src` of image in the `data-original` custom attribute. Now after the dom is ready javascript transfers the link mentioned in `data-original` attribute to `src` attribute. My question is,

Would the browser start downloading the image only after javascript transfers the url to `src` attribute? Or are the images mentioned in `data-original` attribute downloaded on just loading the page and js only renders them after the dom is ready?

Comment: the browser starts downloading the image only after javascript transfers the url to src attribute

Comment: @user1533609 The problem is that we have to mention inline height and width. What could be better is instantly load images in `src` get the width of image then before the image fully downloads apply lazy loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only when the attribute name is src, browser downloads the source. Data-attributes have no special meaning for browser.

Comment: Could you provide some reference for it?

Comment: Will w3schools be enough? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp   -> **Custom attributes prefixed with "data-" will be completely ignored by the user agent.**